# Float16 is much slower than Float32 and Float64 in numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I was trying to run a code snippet which looks like,

```
import numpy as np
import time

def estimate_mutual_info(X, neurons, bins = 5):
    xy = np.histogram2d(X, neurons, bins)[0]
    x = np.histogram(X, bins)[0]
    y = np.histogram(neurons, bins)[0]
    ent_x = -1 * np.sum( x / np.sum(x) * np.log( x / np.sum(x)))
    ent_y = -1 * np.sum( y / np.sum(y) * np.log( y / np.sum(y)))
    ent_xy = -1 * np.sum( xy / np.sum(xy) * np.log( xy / np.sum(xy)))
    return (ent_x + ent_y - ent_xy)

tic = time.time()
X = np.random.rand(12000, 1200)
Y = np.random.rand(12000, 10)
for j in Y.T:
    mi = 0
    for i in range(X.shape[1]):
        mi += estimate_mutual_info(X.T[i], j, bins = 2)
    print(mi)
toc = time.time()
print(str(toc - tic)+" seconds")
```

To increase the speed, I used `float16`, hoping to see some improvement, but `float16` was much slower than `float32` and `float64`.

```
X = np.random.rand(12000, 1200).astype('float16')
Y = np.random.rand(12000, 10).astype('float16')
```

changing them to `float16` results in execution time of `84.57 seconds`, whereas `float64` and `float32` executed for `36.27 seconds` and `33.25 seconds` respectively. I am not sure, what causes this poor performance for `flaot16`. My processor is `64 bit`, using `python3.7` and `numpy-1.16.2`. I don't think 64 bit processor treats all 16 bit, 32 bit and 64 bit indifferent. Any correction and insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that your processor does not natively support FP16 arithmetic, so it's all being done in software, which is, of course, much slower.

In general, consumer Intel processors don't support FP16 operations.

Answer (score 4):

it is happening because there is no equivalent of float16 in c.

since python is based on c, as there is no equivalent of that in c, numpy created a method to perform for float16.

( float is a 32 bit IEEE 754 single precision Floating Point Number1 bit for the sign, (8 bits for the exponent, and 23* for the value), i.e. float has 7 decimal digits of precision)

Becacause of this( process making equivalent to work on float16) `float16` is slower than `float32` or `float64`

Comment: "because there is no equivalent of float16 in c" Even given a C/C++ standard type (e.g. std::float16_t https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1467r9.html), the biggest bottleneck is that float16 addition is still done via software emulation rather than the FPU.