# Why are numpy operations with float32 significantly faster than float64?

Tags: python, numpy

Doing some optimizing I noticed that switching from float64 to float32 improves run time a *lot* with some numpy ops. 5x in the example below. I know that data types are just handled differently and have hardware dependencies and such (see questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15340781) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56697332)). But why specifically am I seeing the following, and is there anything I can do to make 64 bit as fast?

```
import numpy as np
import timeit


arr64 = np.random.random(size=10000).astype(np.float64)
arr32 = np.random.random(size=10000).astype(np.float32)

time64 = timeit.timeit(lambda :np.exp(arr64), number=10000)
time32 = timeit.timeit(lambda :np.exp(arr32), number=10000)

print(f'64bit time: {time64}')
print(f'32bit time: {time32}')

64bit time: 0.797928056679666
32bit time: 0.15939769614487886
```

Note I'm on Ubuntu with python 3.9.17 and numpy 1.25.2

Comment: Under the assumption that numpy simply dispatches to the libm math function, likely provided by glibc, you can simply compare the two implementations for [(double) `exp`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_exp.c;h=f95733bdb8fae3f0f1a904e0360a3061983a5aa1;hb=HEAD) and [(float) `expf`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32/e_expf.c;h=6fda116cc55ff1c18fd25755d48b53462405171d;hb=HEAD)

Comment: From pure intuition: An implementation for float can do its math in double, get half the bits correct, cast to float and be done. Double doesn't have a larger type available on all platforms, so it has to work harder to polish away the last few rounding errors

Comment: OS matters less than CPU architecture, probably. I expect jumping between different major CPU architectures will produce different results.

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR:** there is several explanations for this regarding the target math library you actually use on your machine. The major reason in your case is likely that they are not implemented the same way : Numpy as its own implementation for simple-precision numbers while it calls the standard math library implementation for double-precision numbers. The former uses **SIMD instructions** while the later does not. It also turns out **Numpy is often not packaged with performance in mind but compatibility** (so the same generic packages may be provided for all x86-64 CPUs).

---

First of all, some math libraries use **SIMD instructions** (eg. SSE, AVX, Neon) to compute several floating-point items at the same time. The Intel SVML is one of such library. AFAIK, It can be linked to speed up Numpy operations like this. Such instructions operate on *fixed-length* SIMD registers (eg. 128 bits for SSE/Neon, 256 bits for AVX). The thing is double-precision numbers are twice bigger so twice less items fit in a register. This means the amount of work for double-precision numbers is twice bigger resulting in a twice slower execution.

The above point only applies if the target math library uses SIMD instructions though. Scalar instructions are not affected by this problem. However, the latency of double-precision numbers can sometimes big significantly higher than simple-precision numbers (because double-precision requires far more transistors since there is more bits to computes and a longer dependency chain between transistors themselves). On recent mainstream x86-64 architecture both types are equally fast for *scalar* ADD/MUL/FMA operations (but not advanced operations like SQRT). You can check that [here](https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf).

The default math library on Linux is the glibc. It uses a *scalar* implementation by default<sup>0</sup> which is based on a lookup table. Since the lookup table is too small<sup>1</sup> to contain the result of every floating-point value, the result is adjusted using a nth-order polynomial. Double-precision numbers are so precise that the table need to be bigger<sup>2</sup> and the polynomial need to have a significant higher order with double precision. While a bigger lookup-table is generally slower because of possible cache-misses, I do not expect this to be a significant issue because of the large number of items to be computed. **The higher-order polynomial is likely the be responsible for the slowdown**. Indeed, higher order polynomial are computed using a sequence of fuse-multiply-add (FMA) operations resulting in a **dependency chain**. This dependency chain matters since the latency of an FMA is already generally pretty "big" (~4 cycles on mainstream x86-64 processors). That being said, I do not expect this to cause a slowdown of 5x (as we can see on your machine). Maybe just 2x-3x but not more. This means this is likely not the main issue.

At this point, I was surprised and curious about what it could be, so I profiled what is going on my Linux machine (having a i5-9600KF CPU). Here is the results:

- the double-precision computation is about 4 times slower than the simple-precision one so I can mostly reproduce your issue;
- during the double-precision computation, the two main expensive functions are `__ieee754_exp_fma` and `exp@@GLIBC_2.29`. This shows that Numpy uses the glibc on my machine (as expected);
- during the simple-precision computation, 99% of the time is spent in Numpy so the glibc is not even used to compute the exponential in this case!

It turns out **Numpy apparently has its own implementation of `exp` for simple-precision numbers**! This means there is no need to even call an external function from another library in this case (expensive). And there's more : it turns out **this simple-precision implementation of Numpy actually uses SIMD instructions while the one of the glibc does not**. I found out that by analyzing performance counters of my processors. It looks like the main function responsible to compute that in Numpy is called `npy_exp` (the file [`npy_math_internal.h.src`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h.src) calls it).

SIMD implementations can be much faster in simple-precision. However, they are not so fast for double-precision because of the two aforementioned factors : less items per SIMD register and more FMA instructions required to reach the requested higher precision. Double-precision SIMD implementation only worth it when the processor provide wide SIMD registers and low-latency FMA instructions<sup>3</sup>. This was not initially the case on most processors a decade ago<sup>4</sup> : 128-bit SSE was the main standard SIMD instruction set on x86-64 CPUs (the 256-bit AVX instruction set was pretty new), there was no widely-accepted FMA instruction set (so the latency is the one of a MUL+ADD) and the latency of floating-point operations was slightly higher. This is probably why Numpy did not implement it, not to mention it takes some time to implement and much more to maintain it. Nowadays, the 512-bit AVX-512 instruction set supported by very recent CPUs is wide enough<sup>5</sup> for double-precision implementations to use SIMD instructions. In fact, Intel developers [added such implementation directly in Numpy](https://github.com/numpy/SVML/tree/1b21e453f6b1ba6a6aca392b1d810d9d41576123/linux/avx512) (see [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/main/numpy/core/src/umath))! This means that if you run on a CPU supporting AVX-512 (eg. AMD Zen4 or Intel IceLake), then the effect should be significantly less visible (still about twice slower). If you want a faster double-precision computation, I advise you try an SIMD math library like the SVML.

**Update:** I run the code on an IceLake server (with AVX-512) and results are significantly closer as expected if Numpy is built correctly. That being said, I discovered that neither standard Ubuntu packages nor PIP seems to enable AVX-512 in Numpy. In fact, the resulting packages was very inefficient so I rebuilt Numpy from scratch to do the job correctly. The double-precision version is only 1.76 times slower. Here are results:

```
Intel CoffeeLake (i5-9600KF) -- from standard debian packages:
    64bit time: 0.39326330599578796
    32bit time: 0.08715593699889723    (x4.51 faster)

Intel IceLake (Xeon 8375C) -- from standard Ubuntu packages:
    64bit time: 1.4964690230001452
    32bit time: 0.5068110490001345     (x2.95 faster)

Intel IceLake (Xeon 8375C) -- from PIP packages:
    64bit time: 0.9384758739997778
    32bit time: 0.550410964999628      (x1.85 faster)

Intel IceLake (Xeon 8375C) -- manual Numpy install enabling AVX-512:
    64bit time: 0.09678016599991679
    32bit time: 0.054961627000011504   (x1.76 faster)
```

Note that IceLake results are faster than the one of CoffeeLake (expected) despite a lower frequency of the IceLake processor (~3.5 GHz turbo frequency for the IceLake Xeon VS ~4.5 GHz for the CoffeeLake one). I advise you to **rebuild Numpy yourself to be sure the target package efficiently use your machine**.

---

**Footnotes:**

0: the glibc has an SIMD implementations for simple-precision numbers, but it looks like it is only called by GCC if `-ffast-math` is provided so it might not be IEEE-754 compliant. 
1: the lookup table cannot be too big because it would require too much memory space and it would also cause expensive cache misses. 
2: the lookup-table is actually 4 times bigger for double-precision numbers in the last version of the glibc (`2**5=32` VS `2**7=128` items). 
3: the latency of the SIMD instructions can be mitigated by computing more items concurrently but this require more SIMD register and the amount of available is limited (especially on old processors), not to mention many people was not aware of this latency issue. 
4: that is >15 years ago since people keep their machine several years and Numpy targets good performance on average machines. 
5: AVX-512 provide also much more registers than SSE (x4) and AVX (x2) so the latency can now be actually more easily mitigated.